# Python 2 How to change list of unicode returned by values_list operation to list of strings

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I performed this operation to retrieve a queryset:

```
Name.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

And it returns these results:

```
[u'accelerate', u'acute', u'bear', u'big']
```

The results are all in unicode (u'). How do I remove them all so that I get the result:

```
['accelerate', 'acute', 'bear', 'big']
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to encode in utf8, you can simply do:

```
definitions_list = [definition.encode("utf8") for definition in definitions.objects.values_list('title', flat=True)]
```

Answer (score 9):

You could call `str` on all the values (note that map is a bit lazy, `list()` added to immediately turn it back into an indexable object):

```
thingy = list(map(str, [u'accelerate', u'acute', u'bear', u'big']))
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
[str(item) for item in [u'accelerate', u'acute', u'bear', u'big']]
```

In the end though, why would you require them to be `str` explicitly; added to a django template (like `{{ value }}`), the u's will disappear.

Comment: As mentioned, you can omit the list() call. I have not run into any issues in doing so. If you can elaborate as to why there would be an issue, I would appreciate that!

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Just tried this in py27 and py34, where py27 returns a `list`, py34 returns a `map` object. Used in a template there's likely no difference. I'll leave the answer as is, as the output of an interpreter is a lot clearer (without the `list()`, py3 will state something like `<builtins.map at 0x7f016df386a0>`).

Answer (score 2):

I think the short way is using `json.dumps()`

```
json.dumps(definitions.objects.values_list('title', flat=True))
```

so you will get the string result as json format like

```
'["accelerate", "acute", "bear", "big" ...]'
```

and if you want to change that into python variable, simply use `eval` as the function, so your code more like this

```
json_format_string = json.dumps(definitions.objects.values_list('title', flat=True))

my_list = eval(json_format_string)  # ['accelerate', 'acute', 'bear', 'big' ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

in python 2.7 justing using map without list is fine as well

```
list_of_python_strings = map(str, [u'accelerate'])
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this

```
my_list = list(map(str, [u'accelerate', u'acute', u'bear', u'big'...]))
```